# ExtJS custom autocomplete for combobox

Tags: extjs, autocomplete

I have following combobox:

```
    var combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {  
    queryMode: 'local', 
    valueField: 'code', 

    store: { 
        fields: ['code', 'text'], 
        ... 
    } 
});
```

I need create autocomplete for code and text. 
I have old version of ExtJs 4.0.2 and a lot of feature doesn't work.

I tried to do something like :

```
listeners: {
    beforequery: function (record) {
        record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
        record.forceAll = true;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Maybe some one know how to create custom autocomplete

Comment: can you add a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) ?

Comment: I'm not very good with ExtJS. What is mean fiddle?

Comment: go to the link http://fiddle.sencha.com/ and create your code there, then you can attach it to here so we can see your full code

Comment: Please find the test example via url [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10co)